# My HTML page won't print my django variable

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

---

First of all sorry for my bad english but i'm french.
I am currently working on a django app and i'm trying to make my HTML page work but it won't and i dont know why.
I followed the tutoriel but i edited some of the code to fit my purpose. And now my page won't print out my variable.
I have python 2.7.5 and Django 1.11.29

[My html page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7zXe.png)

Now this is my code for the HTML :

```html
{% if True %}
        <p> Vrai </p>
        <li>{{ Thriller.title }}</li>
{% else %}
        <p> faux </p>
{% endif %}
<ul>
<p> Paragraphe : </p>
    <li>{{ Thriller.title }}</li>
        <li>{{ Thriller.id }}</li>
</ul>
```

My code for the Django part :

*This is in the models.py file :*

```
from django.db import models
import datetime
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible
from django.utils import timezone

class Artist(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
        def __str__(self):
                return self.name

class Album(models.Model):
        reference = models.IntegerField(null=True)
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
        picture =  models.URLField()
        artists = models.ManyToManyField(Artist, related_name='albums', blank=True)
        def __str__(self):
                return self.title
```

*This is in the views.py file :*

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Album, Artist, Contact, Booking
from django.template import loader

def index(request):
        albums = Album.objects.order_by('-created_at')
        context = {'albums = ': albums}
        template = loader.get_template('polls/index.html')
        return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

This is also my first post here and i dont really know if the post is good or not so forgive it if it's not good !

You can ask me anything you want. Thank's !

Comment: `my code for the HTML` how is this code related to the given view code? What is `Thriller`, where are `albums`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call your context variable in the template instead of `{{ Thriller.title }}` because you did not specify `Thriller` in the context of your view.

Your context in the index() view:

```
context = {'albums = ': albums}
```

Edit this to:

```
context = {'albums': albums}
```

and then in your template, for example to loop over all the album titles:

added the if statement:

```
{% for album in albums %}
    {% if album.title == "Thriller" %}
        <p>{{ album.title }}</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I tested it and it works. In fact the problem is that i can't do : `{% if True %} <p>{{ album.title }}</p> {% endif %}` because it doesn't work. Do i must use `{% for album in albums %}` ?

Comment: great! yes you must use the `albums` context variable to acces it in the template. What exactly do you want to do with the `{% if True %}` statement ?

Comment: Well i dont really want to do `{% if True %}` but more something like `{% if album.title = Thriller %}`. And then, can i access multiple variables in my template ? What if i want more than the `albums` context variable ? can i do something like : `context = {'albums': albums, 'artists': artists}`

Comment: yes you can do that. ill edit my answer to show you how to. And about the context, also yes. thats the way to do it!

Comment: Well that's perfect its exactly what i needed ! thank you very much for your answers and your time !

Answer (score 0):

Try this change to your context

```
context = {'albums': albums}
```

Then in your template do...

```
{% for album in albums %}
    <p>{{ album.title }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```